# Hide an iframe and show the original?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 images if I click on first image it goes to the `allwidget()` method, which generates an `iframe`. I also have another image which calls `homepage()`, when I click on that image, the `iframe` must be hidden and original UI must be displayed.

My code is:

```
function allwidget(url){
  var outer= document.getElementById("outer");
  outer.innerHTML = "<iframe src="+url+" align='left' height='1060px' width='5760px' scrolling='no'  frameborder='0' id='lodex' style='visibility:visible;'></iframe>";
}

function homepage(){
  alert("super");
  var outer= document.getElementById("lodex").style.display="visible";
  if (outer){
    var outer= document.getElementById("lodex").style.display="visible";
    document.getElementById("lodex").style.display="hidden";
  }
}
```

I tried much things, but did not get the solution

Please Help

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply removing the HTML from the `outer` element?

```
function homepage(){
  var outer = document.getElementById("outer");
  outer.innerHTML = "";
}
```

**Edit**:

Or if the outer `element` contained the original UI, you could store it before showing the `iframe` and restore it afterwards:

```
var originalHTML;

function allwidget(url){
  var outer= document.getElementById("outer");
  originalHTML = outer.innerHTML;
  outer.innerHTML = "<iframe src="+url+" align='left' height='1060px' width='5760px' scrolling='no'  frameborder='0' id='lodex' style='visibility:visible;'></iframe>";
}

function homepage(){
  var outer = document.getElementById("outer");
  outer.innerHTML = originalHTML;
}
```